# Convert a binary NodeJS Buffer to JavaScript ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, buffer, arraybuffer

How can I convert a NodeJS binary buffer into a JavaScript ArrayBuffer?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would need to do this?

Comment: a good example would be writing a library that worked with File's in browsers and also for NodeJS files?

Comment: or using a browser library in NodeJS

Comment: Another reason is that a float takes too many bytes of RAM when stored in an `Array`. So to store many floats you need `Float32Array` where it takes 4 bytes. And if you want quick serialization of those floats to a file you need a `Buffer`, as serializing to JSON takes ages.

Comment: I want to know exactly the same thing to send generic data using WebRTC and it's unbelievable that so many answers here have so many likes, but don't answer the actual question...

Comment: `const file = fs.readFileSync(filePath);`, so how do I use this?... 30 minutes later, wow I miss C.

Comment: And ya, I feel ya @WilliamEntriken This is what you get with dynamically typed arrays, a horrible programming interface for basic computer science concepts.

Answer (score 243):

[Instances of `Buffer` are also instances of `Uint8Array`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray) in node.js 4.x and higher.  Thus, the most efficient solution is to access the buffer's own `.buffer` property directly, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394257/1375574.  The Buffer constructor also takes an ArrayBufferView argument if you need to go the other direction.

Note that this will not create a copy, which means that writes to any ArrayBufferView will write through to the original Buffer instance.

---

In older versions, node.js has both ArrayBuffer as part of v8, but the Buffer class provides a more flexible API.  In order to read or write to an ArrayBuffer, you only need to create a view and copy across.

From Buffer to ArrayBuffer:

```
function toArrayBuffer(buffer) {
  const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length);
  const view = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
    view[i] = buffer[i];
  }
  return arrayBuffer;
}
```

From ArrayBuffer to Buffer:

```
function toBuffer(arrayBuffer) {
  const buffer = Buffer.alloc(arrayBuffer.byteLength);
  const view = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
    buffer[i] = view[i];
  }
  return buffer;
}
```

Comment: I'd also recommend you to optimize this by copying integers when possible using DataView. Until `size&0xfffffffe`, copy 32-bit integers, then, if there's 1 byte remaining, copy 8-bit integer, if 2 bytes, copy 16-bit integer, and if 3 bytes, copy 16-bit and 8-bit integer.

Comment: See kraag22's answer for a simpler implementation of half of this.

Comment: Have tested Buffer -> ArrayBuffer with a module intended for browser use and it is working brilliantly. Thanks!

Comment: @SiPlus are you sure that's an optimization? The DataView methods (e.g. `getInt32`) are exceptionally slow compared to accessing array views because of a ton of type-checking that goes on. Here, reading from a DataView is 98% slower, which you won't make up for through 4x fewer iterations you'd get from your approach: http://jsperf.com/haakons-test

Comment: @ZachB Yes, aligning the offset and using Uint32Array should be much better.

Comment: @SiPlus *grin* "should be" and "is" better are not the same; always test "optimizations" before assuming they're optimizations. First off, you actually can't create a DataView from a node Buffer. However, you can use `buffer.readUInt32LE`. This is still 80% slower than Martin's method, see [here for the benchmark](https://gist.github.com/zbjornson/58830044a3389ccc604d). As for aligning offsets, I don't know what you mean. Typed array views *must* always be memory-aligned or the engine will throw an error. The user has no control here. (Node seems to allow non-aligned access to its Buffers.)

Comment: @ZachB I was talking about the typed arrays in browser. Copy the first 0-3 bytes, copy the ints, copy the last 0-3 bytes.

Comment: @SiPlus Huh? The question is about node Buffers, which do not exist in browsers. My statements remain true that byte-wise operations are faster than using a read method, anywhere.

Comment: The 1st example, your returning ab and not view?

Comment: toArrayBuffer should return the ArrayBuffer instance (ab), not the view. The caller needs to be able to create whatever view they need from ArrayBuffer. You cannot to this from Uint8Array

Comment: Why is `ab` returned? There is nothing done with `ab`? I always get `{}` as a result.

Comment: **‘The `slice()` method returns a new `ArrayBuffer` whose contents are a copy of this `ArrayBuffer`'s bytes from begin, inclusive, up to end, exclusive.’** - [MDN `ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/slice)

Comment: **DOWNVOTED**, `slice()`-ing an `ArrayBuffer` **DOES** make a copy.

Comment: TypedArrays have a `buffer` property which is an `ArrayBuffer`.. so there is no need to iterate through each index.

Comment: Why do you call a UintArray a view?

Comment: Uint8Array is one of several different [views](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView) of a portion of memory.

Comment: I had to think about the `++i` for a moment. Turns out to have the same effect as `i++`. So I wonder why you're not incrementing the "usual" way?

Comment: Note that since NodeJS v15.7.0 and v14.18.0 we can use `blob.arrayBuffer()` which returns a **copy** of the blob data.

Answer (score 122):

"From ArrayBuffer to Buffer" could be done this way:

```
var buffer = Buffer.from( new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer) );
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what OP wanted.

Comment: But that's what I wanted googling my problem and glad I've found the solution.

Answer (score 104):

#### No dependencies, fastest, Node.js 4.x and later

`Buffer`s are `Uint8Array`s, so you just need to slice (copy) its region of the backing `ArrayBuffer`.

```
// Original Buffer
let b = Buffer.alloc(512);
// Slice (copy) its segment of the underlying ArrayBuffer
let ab = b.buffer.slice(b.byteOffset, b.byteOffset + b.byteLength);
```

The `slice` and offset stuff is **required** because small `Buffer`s (less than 4 kB by default, half the [pool size](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_property_buffer_poolsize)) can be views on a shared `ArrayBuffer`. Without slicing, you can end up with an `ArrayBuffer` containing data from another `Buffer`. See [explanation in the docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_byteoffset).

**If you ultimately need a `TypedArray`, you can create one without copying the data:**

```
// Create a new view of the ArrayBuffer without copying
let ui32 = new Uint32Array(b.buffer, b.byteOffset, b.byteLength / Uint32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
```

---

#### No dependencies, moderate speed, any version of Node.js

Use [Martin Thomson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12101012/1218408), which runs in *O(n)* time. (See also my replies to comments on his answer about non-optimizations. Using a DataView is slow. Even if you need to flip bytes, there are faster ways to do so.)

#### Dependency, fast, Node.js ≤ 0.12 or iojs 3.x

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcpy to go in either direction (Buffer to ArrayBuffer and back). It's faster than the other answers posted here and is a well-written library. Node 0.12 through iojs 3.x require ngossen's fork (see [this](https://github.com/dcodeIO/node-memcpy/pull/6)).

Comment: It doesn't compile again node > 0.12

Comment: Use ngossen's fork: https://github.com/dcodeIO/node-memcpy/pull/6. See also my new answer if you're using node 4+.

Comment: Where were the `.byteLength` and `.byteOffset` documented?

Comment: @K._ Those properties are inherited from TypedArray: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/byteLength and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/byteOffset

Comment: `var ab = b.buffer.slice(b.byteOffset, b.byteOffset + b.byteLength);` saved my day

Comment: Using `slice()` is *not* O(1), it's O(n) because it creates a copy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/slice

Comment: @MikeFrysinger oops, thanks. Fixed and refreshed answer.

Answer (score 45):

A quicker way to write it

```
var arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(nodeBuffer).buffer;
```

However, this appears to run roughly 4 times slower than the suggested toArrayBuffer function on a buffer with 1024 elements.

Comment: Late addition: @trevnorris [says](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7609#issuecomment-108562986) "starting in [V8] 4.3 Buffers are backed by Uint8Array", so possibly this is faster now...

Comment: See my answer for the safe way to do this.

Comment: Tested it with v5.6.0 and it was the fastest

Comment: This only works because instances of `Buffer` are also instances of `Uint8Array` in Node.js 4.x and higher. For lower Node.js versions you have to implement a `toArrayBuffer` function.

Answer (score 24):

## 1. A `Buffer` is just a *view* for looking into an `ArrayBuffer`.

A `Buffer`, in fact, is a `FastBuffer`, which `extends` (inherits from) `Uint8Array`, which is an octet-unit *view* (“partial accessor”) of the actual memory, an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer).

[**`/lib/buffer.js#L65-L73`**](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a083786c7733b5828102661a04a86884c934950a/lib/buffer.js#L65-L73) <sup>Node.js 9.4.0</sup>

```
class FastBuffer extends Uint8Array {
  constructor(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    super(arg1, arg2, arg3);
  }
}
FastBuffer.prototype.constructor = Buffer;
internalBuffer.FastBuffer = FastBuffer;

Buffer.prototype = FastBuffer.prototype;
```

---

## 2. The size of an `ArrayBuffer` and the size of its *view* may vary.

### Reason #1: `Buffer.from(arrayBuffer[, byteOffset[, length]])`.

With `Buffer.from(arrayBuffer[, byteOffset[, length]])`, you can create a `Buffer` with specifying its underlying `ArrayBuffer` and the view's position and size.

```
const test_buffer = Buffer.from(new ArrayBuffer(50), 40, 10);
console.info(test_buffer.buffer.byteLength); // 50; the size of the memory.
console.info(test_buffer.length); // 10; the size of the view.
```

### Reason #2: `FastBuffer`'s memory allocation.

It allocates the memory in two different ways depending on the size.

- **If the size is less than the half of the size of a *memory pool* and is not 0 (“small”)**: it makes use of a *memory pool* to prepare the required memory.
- **Else**: it creates a dedicated `ArrayBuffer` that exactly fits the required memory.

[**`/lib/buffer.js#L306-L320`**](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a083786c7733b5828102661a04a86884c934950a/lib/buffer.js#L306-L320) <sup>Node.js 9.4.0</sup>

```
function allocate(size) {
  if (size <= 0) {
    return new FastBuffer();
  }
  if (size < (Buffer.poolSize >>> 1)) {
    if (size > (poolSize - poolOffset))
      createPool();
    var b = new FastBuffer(allocPool, poolOffset, size);
    poolOffset += size;
    alignPool();
    return b;
  } else {
    return createUnsafeBuffer(size);
  }
}
```

[**`/lib/buffer.js#L98-L100`**](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a083786c7733b5828102661a04a86884c934950a/lib/buffer.js#L98-L100) <sup>Node.js 9.4.0</sup>

```
function createUnsafeBuffer(size) {
  return new FastBuffer(createUnsafeArrayBuffer(size));
}
```

---

#### What do you mean by a “*memory pool*?”

A [*memory pool*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) is a fixed-size **pre-allocated** memory block for keeping small-size memory chunks for `Buffer`s. Using it keeps the small-size memory chunks tightly together, so prevents [*fragmentation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)) caused by separate management (allocation and deallocation) of small-size memory chunks.

In this case, the memory pools are `ArrayBuffer`s whose size is 8 KiB by default, which is specified in [`Buffer.poolSize`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_property_buffer_poolsize). When it is to provide a small-size memory chunk for a `Buffer`, it checks if the last memory pool has enough available memory to handle this; if so, it creates a `Buffer` that *“views”* the given partial chunk of the memory pool, otherwise, it creates a new memory pool and so on.

---

You can access the underlying `ArrayBuffer` of a `Buffer`. The `Buffer`'s [`buffer` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/buffer) (that is, inherited from `Uint8Array`) holds it. **A *“small”* `Buffer`'s `buffer` property is an `ArrayBuffer` that represents the entire memory pool.** So in this case, the `ArrayBuffer` and the `Buffer` varies in size.

```
const zero_sized_buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(0);
const small_buffer = Buffer.from([0xC0, 0xFF, 0xEE]);
const big_buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(Buffer.poolSize >>> 1);

// A `Buffer`'s `length` property holds the size, in octets, of the view.
// An `ArrayBuffer`'s `byteLength` property holds the size, in octets, of its data.

console.info(zero_sized_buffer.length); /// 0; the view's size.
console.info(zero_sized_buffer.buffer.byteLength); /// 0; the memory..'s size.
console.info(Buffer.poolSize); /// 8192; a memory pool's size.

console.info(small_buffer.length); /// 3; the view's size.
console.info(small_buffer.buffer.byteLength); /// 8192; the memory pool's size.
console.info(Buffer.poolSize); /// 8192; a memory pool's size.

console.info(big_buffer.length); /// 4096; the view's size.
console.info(big_buffer.buffer.byteLength); /// 4096; the memory's size.
console.info(Buffer.poolSize); /// 8192; a memory pool's size.
```

---

## 3. So we need to extract the memory it “*views*.”

An `ArrayBuffer` is fixed in size, so we need to extract it out by making a copy of the part. To do this, we use `Buffer`'s [`byteOffset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/byteOffset) and [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/length), which are inherited from `Uint8Array`, and [the `ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/slice), which makes a copy of a part of an `ArrayBuffer`. The `slice()`-ing method herein was inspired by [@ZachB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394257/4510033).

```
const test_buffer = Buffer.from(new ArrayBuffer(10));
const zero_sized_buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(0);
const small_buffer = Buffer.from([0xC0, 0xFF, 0xEE]);
const big_buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(Buffer.poolSize >>> 1);

function extract_arraybuffer(buf)
{
    // You may use the `byteLength` property instead of the `length` one.
    return buf.buffer.slice(buf.byteOffset, buf.byteOffset + buf.length);
}

// A copy -
const test_arraybuffer = extract_arraybuffer(test_buffer); // of the memory.
const zero_sized_arraybuffer = extract_arraybuffer(zero_sized_buffer); // of the... void.
const small_arraybuffer = extract_arraybuffer(small_buffer); // of the part of the memory.
const big_arraybuffer = extract_arraybuffer(big_buffer); // of the memory.

console.info(test_arraybuffer.byteLength); // 10
console.info(zero_sized_arraybuffer.byteLength); // 0
console.info(small_arraybuffer.byteLength); // 3
console.info(big_arraybuffer.byteLength); // 4096
```

---

## 4. Performance improvement

**If you're to use the results as read-only, or it is okay to modify the input `Buffer`s' contents**, you can avoid unnecessary memory copying.

```
const test_buffer = Buffer.from(new ArrayBuffer(10));
const zero_sized_buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(0);
const small_buffer = Buffer.from([0xC0, 0xFF, 0xEE]);
const big_buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(Buffer.poolSize >>> 1);

function obtain_arraybuffer(buf)
{
    if(buf.length === buf.buffer.byteLength)
    {
        return buf.buffer;
    } // else:
    // You may use the `byteLength` property instead of the `length` one.
    return buf.subarray(0, buf.length);
}

// Its underlying `ArrayBuffer`.
const test_arraybuffer = obtain_arraybuffer(test_buffer);
// Just a zero-sized `ArrayBuffer`.
const zero_sized_arraybuffer = obtain_arraybuffer(zero_sized_buffer);
// A copy of the part of the memory.
const small_arraybuffer = obtain_arraybuffer(small_buffer);
// Its underlying `ArrayBuffer`.
const big_arraybuffer = obtain_arraybuffer(big_buffer);

console.info(test_arraybuffer.byteLength); // 10
console.info(zero_sized_arraybuffer.byteLength); // 0
console.info(small_arraybuffer.byteLength); // 3
console.info(big_arraybuffer.byteLength); // 4096
```

Comment: This is all well and good... but did you actually answer OP's question? If you did, it's buried...

Comment: Great answer! 
In `obtain_arraybuffer`: `buf.buffer.subarray` does not seem to exist. Did you mean `buf.buffer.slice` here?

Comment: @everydayproductive Thank you. As you can see in the edit history, I actually used `ArrayBuffer.prototype.slice` and later modified it to `Uint8Array.prototype.subarray`. Oh, and I did it wrong. Probably got a bit confused back then. It's all good right now thanks to you.

Answer (score 11):

Use the following excellent npm package: [`to-arraybuffer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-arraybuffer).

Or, you can implement it yourself. If your buffer is called `buf`, do this:

```
buf.buffer.slice(buf.byteOffset, buf.byteOffset + buf.byteLength)
```

Comment: [Joyent took it out](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7609#issuecomment-42903457)

Answer (score 6):

A `Buffer` is a `view` for an `ArrayBuffer`.  You can get to the internal wrapped `ArrayBuffer` using the `buffer` property.

This is shared memory, and no copying is required.

```js
const arrayBuffer = theBuffer.buffer
```

If you want a `copy` of the data, create another `Buffer` from the original `Buffer` (NOT from the wrapped ArrayBuffer), and then reference its wrapped `ArrayBuffer`.

```js
const newArrayBuffer = Buffer.from(theBuffer).buffer
```

For reference, going the other direction, from an `ArrayBuffer` to a `Buffer`

```js
const arrayBuffer = getArrayBuffer()
const sharedBuffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer)

const copiedBuffer = Buffer.from(sharedBuffer)
const copiedArrayBuffer = copiedBuffer.buffer
```

Answer (score 2):

You can think of an `ArrayBuffer` as a typed `Buffer`.

An `ArrayBuffer` therefore always needs a type (the so-called "Array Buffer View"). Typically, the **Array Buffer View** has a type of `Uint8Array` or `Uint16Array`.

There is a good article from Renato Mangini on [converting between an ArrayBuffer and a String](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String).

I have summarized the essential parts in a code example (for Node.js). It also shows how to convert between the typed `ArrayBuffer` and the untyped `Buffer`.

```
function stringToArrayBuffer(string) {
  const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(string.length);
  const arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    arrayBufferView[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return arrayBuffer;
}

function arrayBufferToString(buffer) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));
}

const helloWorld = stringToArrayBuffer('Hello, World!'); // "ArrayBuffer" (Uint8Array)
const encodedString = new Buffer(helloWorld).toString('base64'); // "string"
const decodedBuffer = Buffer.from(encodedString, 'base64'); // "Buffer"
const decodedArrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(decodedBuffer).buffer; // "ArrayBuffer" (Uint8Array)

console.log(arrayBufferToString(decodedArrayBuffer)); // prints "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a very useful npm package for this: `buffer`  https://github.com/feross/buffer

It tries to provide an API that is 100% identical to node's Buffer API and allow:

- convert typed array to buffer: https://github.com/feross/buffer#convert-typed-array-to-buffer
- convert buffer to typed array: https://github.com/feross/buffer#convert-buffer-to-typed-array

and few more.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, in my case (Electron: sending buffer to renderer as ArrayBuffer) this simply worked

```
function bufferToArrayBuffer(buffer: Buffer): ArrayBuffer {
  return buffer.buffer as ArrayBuffer;
}
```

and is like 100x faster than

```
function bufferToArrayBuffer(buf) {
    const ab = new ArrayBuffer(buf.length);
    const view = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (let i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i) {
        view[i] = buf[i];
    }
    return ab;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above for a Float64Array and it just did not work.

I ended up realising that really the data needed to be read 'INTO' the view in correct chunks. This means reading 8 bytes at a time from the source Buffer.

Anyway this is what I ended up with...

```
var buff = new Buffer("40100000000000004014000000000000", "hex");
var ab = new ArrayBuffer(buff.length);
var view = new Float64Array(ab);

var viewIndex = 0;
for (var bufferIndex=0;bufferIndex<buff.length;bufferIndex=bufferIndex+8)            {

    view[viewIndex] = buff.readDoubleLE(bufferIndex);
    viewIndex++;
}
```

Comment: That's why Martin Thomson's answer uses Uint8Array -- it is agnostic to the size of the elements. The `Buffer.read*` methods are all slow, also.

Comment: Multiple typed array views can reference the same ArrayBuffer using the same memory. Each value in a Buffer is one byte, so you need to put it into an array with element size of 1 byte. You can use Martin's method, then make a new Float64Array using the same arraybuffer in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This Proxy will expose the buffer as any of the TypedArrays, without any copy. :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-buffer-as-typedarray

It only works on LE, but can be easily ported to BE.
Also, never got to actually test how efficient this is.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: My wording might not sound very official, but it does provide enough information to recreate the solution. 

The solution relies on JavaScript Proxy Object to wrap a native NodeJS Buffer with getters and setters used by TypedArrays. This makes the Buffer instance compatible with any library that requires Typed Array interface.

This is the answer original poster was hoping for, but feel free to dismiss it as it doesn't fit your academic/corporate lingo. See if I care.

Answer (score -2):

NodeJS, at one point (I think it was v0.6.x) had ArrayBuffer support. I created a small library for base64 encoding and decoding [here](https://github.com/arunjitsingh/base64), but since updating to v0.7, the tests (on NodeJS) fail. I'm thinking of creating something that normalizes this, but till then, I suppose Node's native `Buffer` should be used.

Answer (score -6):

I have already update my node to Version 5.0.0
And I work work with this:

```
function toArrayBuffer(buffer){
    var array = [];
    var json = buffer.toJSON();
    var list = json.data

    for(var key in list){
        array.push(fixcode(list[key].toString(16)))
    }

    function fixcode(key){
        if(key.length==1){
            return '0'+key.toUpperCase()
        }else{
            return key.toUpperCase()
        }
    }

    return array
}
```

I use it to check my vhd disk image.

Comment: This looks like a specialized (and slow) serialization-based method, not a generic method for converting to/from Buffer/ArrayBuffer?

Comment: @ZachB    it is generic method for V5.0.0+[only] = =.

Comment: `toArrayBuffer(new Buffer([1,2,3]))` -> `['01', '02', '03']` -- this is returning an array of strings, not integers/bytes.

Comment: @ZachB return array ->return list. i fix int->string for stdout

Comment: In that case it's the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/19544002/1218408, and still without necessary the byte offset checks in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31394257/1218408.