# Node.js net data's toArrayBuffer isn't a real ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm setting up a server that communicates with raw TCP using the 'net' module. I noticed something very strange: the data has a toArrayBuffer method, but it returns something that isn't an ArrayBuffer

```
net.createServer( function(socket) {
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        var ab = data.toArrayBuffer();

        // prints "function ArrayBuffer() { [native code] }"
        console.log( ab.constructor );

        // prints 'false'
        console.log( ab.constructor == ArrayBuffer );
    });
}).listen(port);
```

Why is that the case? Is there something special about the array buffer that's coming from socket data?

Comment: First of all, data is an isntance of BUffer

Comment: right, and I'm calling data.toArrayBuffer()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Buffer#toArrayBuffer` was [introduced in v0.11.8](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/10/30/node-v0-11-8-unstable/) and it seems things are still a bit in flux; in fact, the method was [recently removed due to memory leaks in V8](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/b1a44dfe9eb9297a260d584cf87af1d7b74e7d0a). There's [a thread on the v8-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/CtOe7f6znZU) detailing the issue.

In the meantime, you can convert to an `ArrayBuffer` via the method [Jephron linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23880794/62082).

As to your original question, I'm not sure why `ab.constructor != ArrayBuffer`; I'm not very familiar with the internals of V8, but you can see [in the original code](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/6337/files#diff-f3bc5343c176e5c3d97689fbda961fadR554) that it was returning a `v8::ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: it's quite possible that ArrayBuffer created in C++ are not instances of `ArrayBuffer` constructor. Anyway, `toArrayBuffer` method is badly broken and doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS, buffers are represented by the [Buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) object. `socket.on('data')` passes its callback a buffer object as seen [here](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_data). Here's a thread that covers the conversion of Buffer to ArrayBuffer in Node

[Convert a binary NodeJS Buffer to JavaScript ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609289/convert-a-binary-nodejs-buffer-to-javascript-arraybuffer)