# Writing then Reading back a TypeBuffer to/from a file gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, io

After running this code:

```
var arr = new Uint32Array(16);
for (var i=0; i<16; ++i) arr[i] = i;
fs.writeFileSync("arr",new Uint8Array(arr).buffer);
console.log([].slice.call(new Uint32Array(fs.readFileSync("arr"))));
```

The expected output is:

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]
```

But, instead, it produces this output:

```
[ 91, 111, 98, 106, 101, 99, 116, 32, 65, 114, 114, 97, 121, 66, 117, 102, 102, 101, 114, 93 ]
```

A hexdump of the `arr` file shows this:

```
0000000 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 41 72 72 61 79 42 75 66
0000010 66 65 72 5d
```

Why does the produced output not match the expected output?

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this issue? Did you observe the content of the new `"arr"` file? That should give you a big clue.

Comment: This problem is incompletely specified. What is the "something else" you are observing? Don't expect people to have to run your code to answer your question. Some people do but realize that a lot of experienced posters on this site answer simply by reading the question (note that a lot of high rep users answer with "this code is not tested" desclaimers)

Comment: @Mike that was a very good edit, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`buffer` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/buffer) of a `TypedArray` (`Uint8Array` in this case) is an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer), which is not the same as a [node.js `Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). If you try to read/write an `ArrayBuffer` to a file when the `fs` module is expecting a node.js `Buffer`, it's not going to work.

However, you can [convert between the two any number of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609289/convert-a-binary-nodejs-buffer-to-javascript-arraybuffer). The simplest change to your code to make it work as expected would be to simply initialize a `Buffer` from `arr` instead of trying to use the `.buffer` property:

```
var arr = new Uint32Array(16);
for (var i=0; i<16; ++i) arr[i] = i;
fs.writeFileSync("arr", new Buffer(arr)); // <-- HERE
console.log([].slice.call(new Uint32Array(fs.readFileSync("arr"))));
```

Outputs:

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]
```

And, for completeness, a hex dump of the `arr` file looks like:

```
0000000 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
```

Comment: I'd never have guessed that. I always assumed `node.js` Buffers and ArrayBuffers were the same. Thank you very much.