# nodejs binary websocket mimetype handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, binary, blob

i'm not 100% sure but from what i read when i send a blob (binary data) over websocket, the blob does not contain any file information. (Also the official specification states that wesockets only send the raw binary)

1. the filesize
2. the mimetype
3. user info (explain later)

i'm using https://github.com/websockets/ws

**Testing:**

Sending directly the blob from an input file.

```
ws.send(this.files[0]) //this should already contain the info
```

Creating a new blob with the native javascript api from file setting the proper mimetype.

```
ws.send(new Blob([this.files[0]],{type:this.files[0].type})); //also this
```

on both sides you can get only the effective blob without any other information.

**Is it possible to append let's say a 4kb predefined json data converted also to binary that contains important information like the mimetype and the filesize,
and then just split off the 4kb when needed?**

> {"mime":"txt/plain","size":345}____________4KB_REST_OF_THE_BINARY

**OR**

```
ws.send({"mime":"txt\/plain","size":345})
ws.send(this.files[0])
```

Even if the first one is the **worst solution** ever it would allow me to send everything in one time.

The second one has a big problem:

it's a chat that allows to send also files like documents,images,music videos.

i could write some sort of handshaking system when sending the file/user info before i send the binary data.

**BUT**

if another person sends also a file, as it's async, the handshaking system has no chance to determine wich file is the right one for the correct user and mimetype.

**So how do you properly send a binary file in a multiuser async envoirement?**

i know i can convert to base64 but thats 30% bigger.

btw. Totally **disappointed with Apple**... while chrome shows every binary data properly, my ios devices are not able to handle blob's, only images will show in blob or base64 format, not even a simple txt file. Basically only a `<img>` tag can read dynamic files.

How everything works (now):

1. user sends a file
2. nodejs gets the binary data, also user info... but not mimetype,filename,size.
3. nodejs broadcasts the raw binary file to all the users.(can't specify user & file info)
4. clients create a bloburl (who send that? XD).

**EDIT**

what i have now:

**client 1** (sends a file)CHROME

```
fileInput.addEventListener('change',function(e){
 var file=this.files[0];
 ws.send(new Blob([file],{
  type:file.type //<- SET MIMETYPE
 }));
 //file.size
},false);
```

note: `file` is already a blob ... but this is how you would normally create a new blob specifying the mimetype.

**server** (broadcasts the binary data to the other clients)NODEJS

*aaaaaand the mimetype is gone...*

```
ws.addListener('message',function(binary){
 var b=0,c=wss.clients.length;
 while(b<c){
  wss.clients[b++].send(binary)
 }
});
```

**client 2** (recieves the binary)CHROME

```
ws.addEventListener('message',function(msg){
 var blob=new Blob([msg.data],{
      type:'application/octet-stream' //<- LOST
     });
 var file=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
},false);
```

note: `m.data` is already a blob ... but this is how you would normally create a new blob specifying the mimetype witch is lost.

In **client 2** i need the mimetype and naturally i also need the info about the user, wich can be retrieved from **client 1** or the **server** (not a good choice)...

Comment: Have you thought about using BinaryPack? https://github.com/binaryjs/node-binarypack https://github.com/binaryjs/js-binarypack

Comment: sorry, no, i'm trying to achieve it with ws (websockets)

Comment: Right, BinaryPack is what BinaryJS uses to stream files, etc. over websockets http://binaryjs.com/

Comment: i  mean i'm trying to get this to work without another external lib. i searching for a proper way using this type of binary sending system ...https://github.com/websockets/ws

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're a bit out of luck with this because Node doesn't support the `Blob` interface and so any data you send or receive in Binary with Node is just Binary. You would have to have something that knew how to interpret a Blob object.

Here's an idea, and let me know if this works. Reading through the documentation for `websockets\ws` it says it supports sending and receiving `ArrayBuffers`. Which means you can use [TypedArrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray).

Here's where it gets nasty. You set a certain *fixed* `n` number of bytes at the beginning of every `TypedArray` to signal the mime type encoded in utf8 or what have you, and the rest of your `TypedArray` contains your file's bytes.

I would recommend using `UInt8Array` because `utf8` characters are 8 bits long and your text will probably be readable when encoded that way. As for the file bits you'll probably just end up writing those down somewhere and appending an ending to it.

Also note, this method of interpretation works both ways whether from Node or in the Browser.

This solution is really just a form of type casting and you might get some unexpected results. The fixed length of your mime type field is crucial.

Here it is illustrated. Copy, paste, set the image file to whatever you want and then run that. You'll see the mime type I set pop out.

```
var fs = require('fs');


//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609289/convert-a-binary-nodejs-buffer-to-javascript-arraybuffer
function toUint8Array(buffer) {
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length);
  var array = new Uint8Array(ab);

  for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
    array[i] = buffer[i];
  }

  return array;
}

//data is a raw Buffer object
fs.readFile('./ducklings.png', function (err, data) {
  var mime = new Buffer('image/png');
  var allBuffed = Buffer.concat([mime, data]);
  var array = toUint8Array(allBuffed);
  var mimeBytes = array.subarray(0,9); //number of characters in mime Buffer
  console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, mimeBytes));
});
```

Here's how you do it on the client side:

**SOLUTION A: GET A PACKAGE**

Get [buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer), an implementation of Node's Buffer API for browsers. The solution to concatenate Byte buffers will work exactly as before. You can append fields like To: and what not as well. The way you format your headers in order to best serve your clients will be an evolving process I'm sure.

**SOLUTION B: OLD SCHOOL**

**STEP 1: Convert your Blob to an ArrayBuffer**

Notes: [How to convert a String to an ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers)

```
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.addEventListener('loadend', function () {
//Asynchronous action in part 2.
  var message = concatenateBuffers(headerStringAsBuffer, fr.result);
  ws.send(message);
});
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

**STEP 2: Concatenate ArrayBuffers**

```
function concatenateBuffers(buffA, buffB) {
  var byteLength = buffA.byteLength + buffB.byteLength;
  var resultBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteLength);
  //wrap ArrayBuffer in a typedArray/view
  var resultView = new Uint8Array(resultBuffer);
  var viewA = new Uint8Array(resultBuffer);
  var viewB = new Uint8Array(resultBuffer);
  //Copy 8 bit integers AKA Bytes
  resultView.set(viewA);
  resultView.set(viewB, viewA.byteLength);
  return resultView.buffer
}
```

**STEP 3: Receive and Reblob**

I'm not going to repeat how to convert the concatenated String bytes back into a string because I've done it in the server example, but for turning the file bytes into a blob of your mime type is fairly simple.

```
new Blob(buffer.slice(offset, buffer.byteLength), {type: mimetype});
```

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/robnyman/1875241) by `robnyman` goes into further details on how you would use an image transmitted via XHR, put it into localstorage, and use it in an image tag on your page.

Comment: yes this is exactly what i'm trying to explain in this question. the "first solution" would be using a UInt8Array to store that info.... but how? keep in mind that javascript on the clientside needs to endoce and decode the binary data... nodejs just has to passtrough the message.... that way i could send everything in binary.

Comment: it would be even better if i the size of the binary info could be variable.like thew id3 or exif...

Comment: @coco, can you convert ArrayBuffer to a Blob on Node or in the Browser? In the Browser makes sense because Blob just takes a bunch of bytes and throws them in a special bucket with some nice methods. It won't be able to infer that those bytes were once a JavaScript Object. If JavaScript were a Typed language you would get an error, but since it's not I reckon you can turn just about anything into a Blob.

Comment: Also, the reason I recommended the fixed length mime type field is so that you don't have to send another message signaling the length of that field in the array. You could also use some sort of signal character to specify that the mime type message has ended. <CRLF> a.k.a. new line is a common one.

Comment: In your example you show the server to do the math.... but if you read the question again you will see that the server is only a bridge/passtrough... it's client to client.... the clients need to encode/decode the binary data. Problem: the mimetype gets lost inside the server. Solution: encode the mimetype and other info inside the binary file. HOW?? solution2 send fileinfo -> get response -> send binary. HOW to handle multiple users/files ?

Comment: Also.. the solution "oldshool" would be the fisrt solution i was thinking of... but it the final binary is an arraybuffer... i need a blob. while this is a resolvable problem ... at the other side i need to split everything again. And that is where it gets hard...considering that i need to somehow specify a maximum length......

Comment: anyway oneup for the oldshool solution... Sending a blob needs less bandwich than sending an arraybuffer. raw rinary = blob

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily need to specify a maximum length. You could write a method that iterates through each Byte from the beginning of the buffer and builds a String from it until you get a new line character. The function would return the Header String, and then you could use that to find the offset in your ArrayBuffer at which to start reading Bytes into a Blob. I also added details on converting ArrayBuffers to Blobs.

Comment: Also, an ArrayBuffer is raw binary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer

A Blob is an immutable file like object of immutable raw data: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

An ArrayBuffer just gives you the flexibility of putting whatever the heck you want in it and having it come out the other side as you expected it to.

Comment: hah.. sup!! "ou could write a method that iterates through each Byte from the beginning of the buffer and builds a String from it until.." i totally don't know how i could achieve that??? do i ask to much if yoiu enlight me more about that? JSON has no newlines ... so it would be perfect separator.

Comment: Use a for loop on a Uint8Array and use the String.fromCharCode method on each index. I think you should go ahead and give me the answer on this one though and if you have any more questions ask them in their own question space. More rep for me and you eh?

Comment: put the loop inside the answer and everyone has a 100% complete answer and can send multiple data with websockets!!!!!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74851/discussion-between-breedly-and-cocco).

Answer (score 0):

I liked @Breedly's idea of prepending a fixed length byte array to indicate mime type of the ArrayBuffer so I created this [npm package](https://github.com/miguelmota/arraybuffer-mime) that I use when dealing with websockets but maybe others' might find it useful.

Example usage

```
const {
  arrayBufferWithMime,
  arrayBufferMimeDecouple
} = require('arraybuffer-mime')

// some image array buffer
const uint8 = new Uint8Array(1)
uint8[0] = 1
const ab = uint8.buffer

const mime = 'image/png'
const abWithMime = arrayBufferWithMime(ab, mime)

const {mime, arrayBuffer} = arrayBufferMimeDecouple(abWithMime)

console.log(mime) // "image/png"
console.log(arrayBuffer) // ArrayBuffer
```