# How to return ArrayBuffer to the client by Nodejs

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, arraybuffer

I want to use Node.js to return `arrayBuffer` to the client, but I found some problems.

my node `server.js`:

```
res.write(new Buffer([0,1,2]));
res.writeHead(200,{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*','Access-Control-Allow-Method':'GET,POST','Content-Type':'application/octet-stream'});
res.end();
```

and my client code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.open("post","http://localhost:8008/");
xhr.onload = function(data){
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log('succuess');
        console.log(typeof this.response);
    }
}
```

but the chrome console error:

```
POST http://localhost:8008/ net::ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609289/convert-a-binary-nodejs-buffer-to-javascript-arraybuffer

Comment: thanks, but my question is how to solve the error when  I send the arraybuffer to client

Comment: Could you show all headers of the request/response shown in the Chrome network tab?

Comment: request:Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyPMvpTJ4opJKYx3N
Origin:null
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36

Comment: and there is no response header because the request is failed

Comment: Taking into account your request is POST, what data do you send?

Comment: Have you tried to set `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header?

Comment: to add set this header where? request or response?

Comment: just now I added this header to response header, but the same error shows