# Node.js Buffer from string not correct

Tags: node.js

To create a utf-8 buffer from a string in javascript on the web you do this:

```
var message = JSON.stringify('ping');
var buf = new TextEncoder().encode(message).buffer;
console.log('buf:', buf);
console.log('buf.buffer.byteLength:', buf.byteLength);
```

This logs:

```
buf: ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 6 } 
buf.buffer.byteLength: 6
```

However in Node.js if I do this:

```
var nbuf = Buffer.from(message, 'utf8');
console.log('nbuf:', nbuf);
console.log('nbuf.buffer:', nbuf.buffer);
console.log('nbuf.buffer.byteLength:', nbuf.buffer.byteLength);
```

it logs this:

```
nbuf: <Buffer 22 70 69 6e 67 22>
nbuf.buffer: ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 8192 }
nbuf.buffer.byteLength: 8192
```

The byteLength is way to high. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Why `byteLength`? That seems like an implementation detail, as there's no `byteLength` property in the [API](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html). What's the value of `nbuf.length`?

Comment: @cartant thanks! `nbuf.length` properly gave `6`, but I thought per http://stackoverflow.com/a/12101012/1828637 that `Buffer` is just a `Uint8Array` and doing `nbuf.buffer` gives me a javascript `ArrayBuffer` which has `byteLength`. Howcome the `byteLengthf` of the ArrayBuffer in nbuf is 8192?

Comment: I seem to remember reading that `Buffer` instances are allocated out of larger, underlying buffers - perhaps that's to what the inner `buffer` property refers? - but I'm no expert on the inner workings of Node, so I don't know the definitive answer to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer

> ArrayBuffer.prototype.byteLength Read only
>   *The size, in bytes, of the array*. This is *established when the array is constructed and cannot be changed*. Read only.

It seems you should not assume `byteLength` property to be equal to the actual byte length occupied by the elements in the `ArrayBuffer`.

In order to get the actual byte length, I suggest using `Buffer.byteLength(string[, encoding])`

Documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding

For example,

```
var message = JSON.stringify('ping');
console.log('byteLength: ', Buffer.byteLength(message));
```

correctly gives

> byteLength:  6