# How to insert Javascript's Arraybuffer to mongodb via Node.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm working with storing 3d models into mongodb.

In one case, I want to store all the vertex data (which is an ArrayBuffer) of a 3d model as binary data just like this:

```
{
  name: model_1,
  vertexBuffer: <Binary Data>
}
```

How can I store the arraybuffer as binary data in mongodb via node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Binary()](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Binary.html) function :

```
const bson = require('bson');

{
  name: model_1,
  vertexBuffer: new bson.Binary(<Binary Data>)
}
```

But you may need to convert ArrayBuffer to Buffer. Please read [Convert a binary NodeJS Buffer to JavaScript ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609289/convert-a-binary-nodejs-buffer-to-javascript-arraybuffer)

Comment: Thank you so much, I forget to convert ArrayBuffer to Buffer !

Comment: @htxu You can accept the answer if you believe it solves your problems, see [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).