# Angular 5 HttpClient post raw binary data

Tags: angular, typescript, protocol-buffers

My WebApp needs to communicate with my server via ProtBuf. For this to be possible, I need to be able to post the raw binary data.

This is the code I'm using right now. The problem with this is that `HttpClient` encodes the Uint8Array as a JSON array, so that the result is not a valid protobuffer anymore:

```
const message = LoginRequest.fromObject({
  code: code,
  username: username,
  password: password
});

const buffer: Uint8Array = LoginRequest.encode(message).finish();

this.http.post('https://api.myserver.com', buffer)
  .subscribe(/*...*/);
```

`HttpClient.post` accepts some options, where you can set `responseType` to `json`, `text`, `blob` or `arraybuffer`. But this just sets the expected type of the response, the body of the request still gets encoded as JSON.

Does `HttpClient` have the possibility to send unencoded bodies?

Edit: This is the body I receive at the server:

`{"0":10,"1":3,"2":97,"3":98,"4":99,"5":18,"6":5,"7":97,"8":100,"9":109,"10":105,"11":110,"12":26,"13":8,"14":112,"15":97,"16":115,"17":115,"18":119,"19":111,"20":114,"21":100}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As it can be seen in the [reference](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post), the type of request `body` is `any`, this suggests that it is free-form. `HttpClient` uses `HttpRequest` to represent requests, which uses [`serializeBody` method](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.0/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L233-L237) to transform request body:

> Transform the free-form body into a serialized format suitable for transmission to the server.

It accepts a number of body types, all of them are stringified accordingly. Raw body is expected to be `Blob`, `ArrayBuffer` or a string. So `Uint8Array` should be converted to one of them, for example:

```
const arr: Uint8Array = LoginRequest.encode(message).finish();
const buffer: ArrayBuffer = arr.buffer;
```

Comment: The answer given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609289/convert-a-binary-nodejs-buffer-to-javascript-arraybuffer solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
this.httpClient.post('.../service/', new Blob([gzip(JSON.stringify(obj))]),
```

it's used in an A7 app, though code still contains same comment