# How to specify the stream to upload a file to OneDrive using MS Graph

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am working with Angular 9 to upload a file to OneDrive using MS Graph.

I got so far as to upload an empty file and upload a file with some bogus content (the datatype). I suppose I am not adding the right stream,

I read “[Upload or replace the contents of a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)” and another bunch of documents. it says: **The contents of the request body should be the binary stream of the file to be uploaded.**

In the same document, in the **Example (updating an existing file)** section it says:

```
const stream = The contents of the file goes here.; 
let res = await client.api('/me/drive/items/{item-id}/content') .put(stream);
```

which is useless.

I am getting the files from an  object, I use

```
onChangeFilePicker() {
    this.upload(this.filePicker.nativeElement.files)
}
```

which gives me an array of File objects.

Then I tried many different ways, the last one

```
    private async uploadFile(graphClient: Client, folderItemId: string, file: File) {
      file.arrayBuffer().then((buffer: ArrayBuffer) => {
        let u8Buffer = new Uint8Array(buffer)
        graphClient
          .api(`/me/drive/items/${folderItemId}:/${file.name}:/content`)
          .post(u8Buffer.values())
            .then(response => {
                console.log('ok')
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error.stack)
            })        
      })
  }
```

which creates a file with two bytes.

Do you have any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: I tried this in past and it worked:

string path = "D:\\LessThan4MB.txt";
byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    var item = await _client.Me.Drive.Items[FolderID]
            .ItemWithPath("LessThan4MB.txt")
            .Content
            .Request()
            .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
}

You can try this approach with memory stream and PutAsync<DriveItem> request to see if it fits your scenario.

Comment: I will update it in the answer. so that you can read the code snippet properly.

Comment: I read your response, thank you. It is C# so I used the equivalent ideas in TypeScript. But It does not work. I keep on getting a file with corrupted content.

Comment: @DigitalOnion Hi. I am trying to upload the files to one drive and I am not able to get the access token. Can you help me out with how you have done this?. I have also set a bounty on a question if you could answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was about encoding and the Graph Client.

I skipped the Graph Client and went for pure Graph API requests. This requires to pass the Authentication Token, and requires to put together the Body of the request. Though I had similar results, those got fixed when I encoded the ArrayBuffer as a UInt8Array, like this:

To get the Authentication Token:

```
  let graphScopes = new MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions(["Files.ReadWrite.All"]);    
  let userAgentApplication = new UserAgentApplication( { auth: this.authConfiguration} )
  let authProvider = new ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider(userAgentApplication, graphScopes );
  
  await authProvider.getAccessToken().
  .then(
    token => {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        })
```

Then to transform the Array Buffer (as suggested at: [Angular 5 HttpClient post raw binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354943/12514267))

```
      file.arrayBuffer().then( buffer => {            
          let body = new Uint8Array(buffer)
          let uIntBody = body.buffer;
```

and finally making the HttpClient PUT Request:

```
async experimentHTTPPostFile(parentId: string, file: File) {    
  let graphScopes = new MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions(["Files.ReadWrite.All"]);    
  let userAgentApplication = new UserAgentApplication( { auth: this.authConfiguration} )
  let authProvider = new ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider(userAgentApplication, graphScopes );
  
  await authProvider.getAccessToken()
  .then(
    token => {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        })

        file.arrayBuffer().then( buffer => {            
          let body = new Uint8Array(buffer)
          let uIntBody = body.buffer;
        
          let url = `${this.MS_GRAPH_BASE_URL}/me/drive/items/${parentId}:/${file.name}:/content`
          this.http.put(url, uIntBody, { headers: headers }).toPromise()
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
          });                
        })            
      }
  ).catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
  })
}
```

It worked perfectly, I tested with PDF, JPEG and other binary files.

I tried doing the same UInt8 transformation of the buffer with the Graph Client graphClient.api(...).put(...), and it does not fix the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear the above solution helped you moving forward.

Comment: Yes, it helped thank you. Seems like the subject does not have good or finished documentation and articles are rolling out slowly. Thanks again.