# Use buffer in napajs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, parallel-processing, napa

I was trying to find multithreading support for JavaScript, and then came across *napa*, but in the list of supported API, there's **no buffer**.
 But in the project I've been working, we are passing buffer as an argument to functions which are required to be multithreaded,

- can we use node zone from another zone for computing calculations regarding buffer?
- If so how? If not, is there any other way or should I switch to using other library which unfortunately have much higher overhead cost?

EDIT:- I am trying to implement multithreading where we require something like the following class to be transported:-

```
class Multi{
  a(){
    ...
    returns buffer; 
  }
  ... other properties
}
```

Comment: There's far too little detail in here about what you're actually trying to do to have any idea what to recommend.

Comment: Added explaination, please have a look again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Napa.js does not directly support `Buffer` itself, it supports a range of "[transportable](https://github.com/Microsoft/napajs/blob/master/docs/api/transport.md#transportable-types)" JavaScript types including Uint8Array, ArrayBuffer, and SharedArrayBuffer. Instances of Buffer are also instances of Uint8Array ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609289/convert-a-binary-nodejs-buffer-to-javascript-arraybuffer)), so you can send and receive Uint8Array or Uint16Array objects.

You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609289/convert-a-binary-nodejs-buffer-to-javascript-arraybuffer) to see how you can convert buffers to and from Uint8Array objects. Keep in mind that since Napa.js currently does not directly support `Buffer` module, these conversions should take place in the main thread and not the workers. But you can normally operate on the typed arrays inside the zone workers.

Hope this helps!