# Underlying ArrayBuffer of Buffer created with Buffer.from contains weird Values in Node.js 8.6.0

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have encountered a very weird behavior I do not understand after trying to debug my application for half a day. Have a look at the following snippet:

```js
const buffer = Buffer.from([12, 34, 56, 78, 90]);
const dataView = new DataView(buffer.buffer);

console.log('buffer byteLength:', buffer.byteLength);
console.log('dataView byteLength:', dataView.byteLength);

console.log('first uint8 in buffer:', buffer.readUInt8(0));
console.log('first uint8 in dataView:', dataView.getUint8(0));
```

For me, the output of this script is:

```
buffer byteLength: 5
dataView byteLength: 8192
first uint8 in buffer: 12
first uint8 in dataView: 99
```

The Node.js version I used is 8.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, despite not noted in the [official documentation of `Buffer.from`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array), the function automatically creates a `Buffer` with *unsafe allocation*, described in the [documentation of `Buffer.allocUnsafe()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_allocunsafe_size).

[There is an answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394257/2477364) hinting that there is a property `Buffer#byteOffset` holding the byte offset for the `Buffer`'s underlying `ArrayBuffer`. This property is not documented for `Buffer` itself, but for `Uint8Array`, [whose API `Buffer` implements](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer).

Extending the original snippet with the following line will produce the expected output.

```js
console.log('first uint8 in dataView:', dataView.getUint8(buffer.byteOffset)); // output: 12
```