# nodejs: read file then parse with DataView

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read a binary file then parse it with DataView, but when passing the buffer from `fs.readFile` to `DataView`, it throws an Error

```
TypeError: First argument to DataView constructor must be an ArrayBuffer
```

here is my code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const buf = fs.readFileSync('./path/to/file');
const dv = new DataView(buf);
```

the reason why I want to `DataView` instead of methods from `Buffer`(`buf.readInt8([offset])`) to read data is that I can share logic between `node` and browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a binary NodeJS Buffer to JavaScript ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609289/convert-a-binary-nodejs-buffer-to-javascript-arraybuffer)

Answer (score -1):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const buf = fs.readFileSync('./path/to/file');
const dv = new DataView(buf.buffer);
```